# define my location on google maps on setMyLocationEnabled eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm developing an app for android with google maps. The problem is that when I activate "setMyLocationEnabled" on the google map, it sets my location to Hong Kong but I'm in Portugal. But the location given by the locationManager gives me my correct location. Is there a way to define that my location is the location of the locationManager on the "setMyLocationEnabled"?

This gives me my correct location:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

        Lat = myLocation.getLatitude();
        Long = myLocation.getLongitude();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20000, 1, this);
```

But this:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

says that I'm in Hong Kong when I actualy am in Portugal.

How can I define that the "setMyLocationEnabled" has to start on the same position as the locationManager and put the blue dot on that position?

Answer (score 0):

In using [My Location layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#the_my_location_layer), please note as stated,

> Before enabling the My Location layer, you must ensure that you have the required runtime location permission.

Either the coarse location permission:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp" >
  ...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  ...
</manifest>
```

Or the fine location permission:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp" >
  ...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  ...
</manifest>
```

However, as discussed in [Making Your App Location-Aware](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

> The [Google Play services location APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary) are preferred over the Android framework location APIs (android.location) as a way of adding location awareness to your app. If you are currently using the Android framework location APIs, you are strongly encouraged to switch to the Google Play services location APIs as soon as possible.